# Is $K[\alpha,\beta]$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, proof-explanation, galois-theory

I am studying some theory of functions on Algebraic Curves and I have stuck at the following point.

Let $K$ be a field, let $L/K$ be a field extension, let $C$ be the  curve $C:\ f(X,Y)=0_K$ and let $P:=(\alpha,\beta),P':=(\alpha',\beta')\in L\times L$ be two points on $C$, which are conjugate (that is, $g(P)=0\iff g(P')=0,\ \forall g(X,Y)\in K[X,Y])$.

In the proof I study, the author claims that **$K[\alpha,\beta] \leq L$ is a a field**. Can we explain why?

I can see that $f(\alpha,\beta)=0_K$, hence $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K[\beta]$ and $\beta$ is algebraic over $K[\alpha]$. So, $K[\alpha,\beta]=K[\beta](\alpha)$ and $K[\alpha,\beta]=K[\alpha](\beta)$. But I can not see why $K[\alpha,\beta]=K(\alpha,\beta)$.

Any explanation for this?

*From the book Codes and Algebraic Curves, by O. Pretzel.*

Comment: The author meant that $L/K$ is algebraic, otherwise it is not true, $L = K(t), f(X,Y)=Y-X,\alpha=\beta=t$

Comment: Dear reuns, I am not sure if he meant that. He proves that "conjugate simple points of $C$ define the same order function". The thing is that in the proof, he writes princely, " Let $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $(\alpha',\beta')$ be conjugate points of $C$ over $K$, and let $E$ and $E'$ be the fields $K[\alpha,\beta]$ and $K[\alpha',\beta']$."

Comment: Are you given that $f$ and $g$ are polynomials with coefficients in either $K$ or $L$?  This isn't explicit, so I'm currently imagining a horrible transcendental $f$, defined by some axiom of choice argument to have zero or one zeroes on the conjugates of any algebraic, thwarting the existence of $P$.

Comment: If understand correctly the comment, $C$ is the curve that is defined by $f(X,Y)=0_K$, where $f(X,Y)\in K[X,Y]$ is an irreducible polynomial in $K[X,Y]$.

Comment: Conjugate implicitly means that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$.

Comment: @reuns Which tells us that $[K(\alpha):K]<\infty$. But why that?

Comment: I am not used to this conjugate notion. Still, $\alpha\in L$ is algebraic over $K$ if and only if $K[\alpha]$ is a field. Similarly, if $\beta$ is algebraic over $K$, then it is algebraic over $K[\alpha]$. In this case $K[\alpha][\beta]=K[\alpha,\beta]$ is a field. By the way, the notation $R = K(\alpha,\beta)$ might be missleading for your porpuse. How is $R$ defined?

Comment: I haven't looked at Pretzel's book, but given the topic (something I think I am familiar with) it stands to reason that $L/K$ should be finite or at least algebraic. In addition to the points raised by others consider the following. Let $C$ be the curve defined by the equation $f(X,Y)=Y-X^2=0$ over $K=\Bbb{Q}$. The "generic" points $P=(\alpha,\beta)=(\pi,\pi^2)$ and $P'=(\alpha',\beta')=(e,e^2)$ are points on the curve with coordinates in $L=\Bbb{R}$. Because both $\pi$ and $e$ are transcendental over $K$ we have the property $g(P)=0\Leftrightarrow g(P')=0$ for all $g\in\Bbb{Q}[x,y]$,

Comment: (cont'd) But it defies all reason to call $P$ and $P'$ conjugate :-)